# web analytic show 0 visitor since last 2 weeks

Tags: web-analytics

[image]It's been running fine for a year and all of the sudden shows 0 visitors (since the 15th).

1. Services are running under CA
2. Ran the web analytic timer job
3. refresh the page "_layouts/WebAnalytics/Report.aspx?t=PageViewTrend&l=s" same day and day after and still show 0 for "Number of Page Views", "Number of daily unique visitors" etc.

Comment: Still an outstanding issue. Can anyone suggest something?

Comment: Went through this and everything looks good. http://geekswithblogs.net/rgupta/archive/2011/02/16/site-web-analytics-not-updating-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Comment: Have you changed anything about the way the site is addressed recently? Alternate Access Mappings come to mind, but I'm just guessing. It sounds like the usage is getting logged but it's associated with something different now.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is with web analytics? It may be possible that site have 0 visitors.

Comment: Et Tu Brute?  Did you make any changes to the site on the 15th or just previous?  Unless you have passwords that changed on that day or ran out of disk space the services should not just stop.

Answer (score 1):

please try to check free space on a disk where usage logs saved; you can also review files "date modified" properties there.

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure Usage Collection from the SharePoint Central Admin.

Central Administration > Monitoring > Configure usage and health data collection

Please ensure 
Enable usage data collection (is checked)

Events to log:

Content Import Usage 
Content Export Usage 
Page Requests (This option must be checked) 
Feature Use 
Search Query Usage 
Site Inventory Usage 
Timer Jobs 
Rating Usage

After you enable Web Analytics , SharePoint automatically does not start making analytical data unless we specify data that needs to be captured and saved on the analytics service application database.

SharePoint will created a service application database typically named as "WSS_Logging" after you provision Usage Collection Service.

If this service is already present , then I would suggest to reconfigure usage and logging service once again. It should work.

Comment: Did everything everyone suggested and none helped. oh well, I guess I will have recreate the logging and usage service apps.

Comment: @MariaBurton - just curious if you figured this out? or did you have to re-create the Service application?

Answer (score 0):

Go to central administration>Monitoring>Reports>Configure usage and health data collection.
Under "Events to log", ensure that "Page Requests" checkbox is checked